# How to get new coordinates in Battleship game

Tags: javascript

I have a battleship game I'm working on and I would like to get new coordinates if the coordinates are not valid. As of right now If I try to place a random ship sometimes it works sometimes it goes out of bounds and receive an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '4')

I have these two functions placeHorizontal and placeVertical. I am checking to see if the coordinates are valid and if they aren't get new coordinates and place the ship there but having trouble on how to get new coordinates. As you can see by the empty getNewCoords function.

```js
const Gameboard = () => {
  const rows = 10
  const columns = 10
  const board = []
  const missedCoord = []
  const shipArr = []
  const attackCoord = []

  const getBoard = () => [...board]

  const Water = () => {
    let isHit = false
    const hit = () => {
      isHit = true
    };
    return {
      type: "water",
      hit,
      get isHit() {
        if (isHit) {
          return "BLOOP! Miss."
        }
        return "Ship hit!"
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j += 1) {
      board[i][j] = Water()
    }
  }

  // Need to reduce array amount to a single value
  const cellCount = getBoard().reduce((row, col) => row + col.length, 0)

  const validCoords = (x, y) => {
    if (x < 0) {
      return false
    }
    if (x > 9) {
      return false
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      return false
    }
    if (y > 9) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  const getNewCoords = (x, y) => {

  }

  const placeHorizontal = (x, y, ship) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    // Loop through ships length
    for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
      // Change ship.name back to ship
      currentBoard[x][y + i] = ship.name
      shipArr.push(ship)
    }
    return true
  }

  const placeVertical = (x, y, ship) => {
    const check = validCoords(x, y)
    if (!check) {
      const newXandY = getNewCoords(x, y)
      return placeVertical(newXandY)
    }
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    // Loop through ships length
    for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
      // Change ship.name back to ship
      currentBoard[x + i][y] = ship.name
      shipArr.push(ship)
    }
    return true
  }

  function canShipBeHitAgain(x, y) {
    const coords = [x, y]
    const coordStr = JSON.stringify(coords)
    const attackCoordStr = JSON.stringify(attackCoord[0])

    if (coordStr === attackCoordStr) {
      console.log("Cannot hit same spot!")
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  function receiveAttack(x, y) {
    const water = Water()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    if (currentBoard[x][y].hit() && canShipBeHitAgain(x, y)) {
      attackCoord.push([x, y])
      return true
    }
    water.hit()
    missedCoord.push([x, y])
    return false
  }

  function allSunk() {
    shipArr.every((ship) => {
      if (!ship.isSunk()) {
        console.log("All ships are not sunk.")
        return false
      }
      return console.log("All ships are sunk!")
    })
    return true
  }
  return {
    placeVertical,
    placeHorizontal,
    getBoard,
    cellCount,
    receiveAttack,
    allSunk,
    canShipBeHitAgain,
    validCoords
  }
}
```

Here is how I am creating the ai or computer functionality. It currently places the horizontal and vertical ships at random (sometimes).

```js
const createComputer = () => {
  const computerGameboard = Gameboard()
  // const getCompBoard = computerGameboard.getBoard()

  const placeShipHorizontal = (ship) => {
    let x;
    let y;
    do {
      x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
    }
    while (computerGameboard.placeHorizontal(x, y, ship) === false);
    computerGameboard.placeHorizontal(x, y, ship)
    return true
  }

  const placeShipVertical = (ship) => {
    let x;
    let y;
    do {
      x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
    }
    while (computerGameboard.placeVertical(x, y, ship) === false);
    computerGameboard.placeVertical(x, y, ship)
    return true
  }

  const setEnemyBoard = (player) => player.getPlayerBoard

  return {
    computerGameboard,
    setEnemyBoard,
    placeShipHorizontal,
    placeShipVertical
  }
}

const computer = createComputer()
computer.setEnemyBoard(player)
const testShip = createShip(3, "1")
const testShip2 = createShip(3, "2")

computer.placeShipVertical(testShip)
computer.placeShipHorizontal(testShip2)
```

Comment: What is the code you use to `placeVertical`, `placeHorizontal`, in particular what arguments do you pass to these functions?

Comment: I see so I would have to pass the x, y , ship parameters into that getNewCoords function. For the arguments it would be something `placeVertical(3,3,ship)`. I'm having troube seeing how I could translate that into getting new coordinates in `getNewCoords`. @user776686

Comment: I think the errors might be coming from the improper usage of `ship` object. And in order for anyone to be able to help you it'd be good to provide clear repro instructions. It often happens that while working on those instructions, you'll realize the mistake you're making :)

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more if you can please, what makes you think it's improper usage of ship I am curious. I provided more context that is the computer/ai functionality and how they're placed. Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated, have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. @user776686

Comment: I now noticed you updated the code, but the code is broken. When I run it, `computer.setEnemyBoard(player)`  => `player` is undefined, `createShip(3, "1")` => `createShip` is undefined. It's really difficult to help you. Start by helping yourself by making a working example (stackblitz maybe?) . I also think this project might benefit from TypeScript.